# Pointer Arithmetic and Inheritance result in undefined behauviour

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, pointer-arithmetic

When running my program it terminates when executing `cout<<Core32->name()` for the second time. After researching the problem I learned that pointer arithmetic in this case leads to problems. Also i was able to fix the problem by substituting `Core32++;` with `Core32+04;` (Don't really know why this works). Nevertheless my question is why I was able to call the Method `Core32->procfun()` but not `Core32->name()`. I looked up object slicing but it didn't seem to solve my problem.

EDIT: Wanted to know why it only is able to call procfun() but not name().
This is an example from an old exam

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class Prozessor{
public:
    virtual string name()=0;
};

class ARM : public Prozessor{
public:
    virtual string name(){return "VAR";};
    virtual int procbitw()=0;
    string procfun(){return "VFP";};
};

class ARMv7:public ARM{
public:
    int procbitw(){return 32;};
    string procfun(){return "VFP";};
};

class ARMv8:public ARM{
public:
    int procbitw(){return 64;};
    string procfun(){return "VFP, NEON";};
};

int main()
{
    const unsigned int n_cores=4;

    ARM *HetQuadCore[n_cores]={new ARMv7, new ARMv7, new ARMv8, new ARMv8};
    ARMv7* Core32=(ARMv7*)HetQuadCore[0];
    for(int i =0;i<n_cores;i++)
    {
        cout<<Core32->procfun()<<endl;
        cout<<Core32->name()<<endl;
        cout<<"Bandwith is "<<HetQuadCore[i]->procbitw()<<endl;
        Core32++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: why do you want to use `Core32` when you can do the same with `HetQuadCore[i]` ?

Comment: a base class instance is not a child class instance

Comment: It's undefined behavior.  You need to iterate using an `ARM *`, as that is what the array has.

Comment: @NathanOliver It still terminates the problem when calling Core32->name()

Comment: Why isn't `profcun` made `virtual`? I suggest you make it a habit of marking all overridden functions in child-classes as `override`. Like e.g. `string procfun() override { ... }`.

Comment: @PerSchmitz That's the problem with undefined behavior.  It can "work", it can not work.  all bets are off.

Comment: By the way, you don't need to terminate function bodies with `;`, not even inside classes. So e.g. `int procbitw(){return 32;}` (without the last `;`) is valid.

Comment: Remove Core32++, to get the result you want. If you don't want to use Core32 as a pointer to HetQuadCore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're incrementing the wrong thing.

You have an array of pointers, right? And you also have a pointer *to a pointer in that array*.

You're incrementing one of the object pointers, not the array pointer.

```
Array      Hypothetical     Objects              Your pointer
          "array pointer"  (scattered)             "Core32"
                                                       ┃
╔══════╗ «━━━━ aPtr            ╔═══════╗               ┃
║ ptr1 ║━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━»║ ARMv7 ║«━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛
╠══════╣   ↓  ++aPtr           ╚═══════╝
║ ptr2 ║━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓                  ╔═══════╗
╠══════╣   ↓  ++aPtr            ┃  ╔═══════╗  ┏━━━»║ ARMv8 ║
║ ptr3 ║━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓ ┗━»║ ARMv7 ║  ┃    ╚═══════╝
╠══════╣   ↓  ++aPtr          ┃    ╚═══════╝  ┃
║ ptr4 ║━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┓┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┛  ╔═══════╗
╠══════╣   ↓  ++aPtr         ┗━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━»║ ARMv8 ║
║   …  ║                                         ╚═══════╝
╙┄┄┄┄┄┄╜
```

Because those objects are [potentially] scattered about, incrementing `Core32` just gives you nonsense. This can never be guaranteed to work. It'll only appear to work when the `new` calls gave you dynamically-allocated objects adjacent in memory.

You should just use `i` to iterate the array, as you are doing already, or take a pointer `aPtr` that iterates through the elements of the array, then dereference a second time to get the object that the *element* points to.

Comment: I think you just won the ASCII art gold medal.

Comment: @molbdnilo Technically it's Unicode art in this revision :P See also: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/125361/1167

Answer (score 2):

> question is why I was able to call the Method `Core32->procfun()` but not `Core32->name()`

Because the behaviour is undefined.

It is undefined in both cases. One possible behaviour is that *"I was able to call the Method"*. Another possible behaviour is *"my programm it terminates"*.

> Also i was able to fix the problem by substituting Core32++; with Core32+04

One possible behaviour could look like  *"i was able to fix the problem"*, but just because it might appear so, does not mean that the undefined behaviour has been fixed.

The problem is that `Core32` is not a pointer to an element of an array, so incrementing it does not yield a valid object. You might do something like this:

```
for(int i =0;i<n_cores;i++)
{
    if (auto ptr7 = dynamic_cast<ARMv7*>(HetQuadCore[i]))
        cout<<ptr7->procfun()<<endl;
    else if (auto ptr8 = dynamic_cast<ARMv8*>(HetQuadCore[i]))
        cout<<ptr8->procfun()<<endl;
    cout<<HetQuadCore[i]->name()<<endl;
    cout<<"Bandwith is "<<HetQuadCore[i]->procbitw()<<endl;
    Core32++;
}
```

However, it might be better to make `procfun` virtual instead.

Answer (score 0):

You could call `Core32->procfun` because it is not a virtual function (so don't need to access vtable) and don't use any internal data.
It would possibly fail on any access to internal data as `this` parameter is invalid.

Comment: It could theoretically fail even on `Core32->procfun()`, since the code is simply undefined.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ok this is rather guess why particular compiler execute this method properly